# How to make a for loop to automatically make a series of m differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, algorithm, automation

I'm trying to construct a series of differential equations that defines the behavior of m mutually interacting species according to the Lotka-Volterra equations. I figure there must be some clever Mathematica way to define them all in one go without having to manually write out each equation but unfortunately I'm quite inexperienced. How would I do this?

```
n1'[t] == r1 n1[t] (1 + a11 n1[t] + a12 n2[t]+a13 n3[t] ...);
n2'[t] == r2 n2[t] (1 + a22 n2[t] + a21 n1[t]+a23 n3[t] ...);
n3'[t] == r3 n3[t] (1 + a33 n3[t] + a31 n1[t]+a32 n3[t] ...);
n4'[t] == r4 n4[t] (1 + a44 n4[t] + a41 n1[t]+a42 n4[t] ...);
.
.
.
```

Comment: while possible, personally I would use definitions instead of symbol names per se, e.g. `n[1]'[t] == r[1] n[1][t] (1 + a[1,1] n[1][t] ...)`, together with either a `Table` or `Array` to vary the indices!

Comment: (note by the way that `==` does not define things; it's merely part of an expression. so, you'll want to keep these expressions around in some kind of container, like a list (as would be produced by a `Table`), and store *that* in a variable. in that case you'll want to avoid the semicolon at the end!)

Answer (score 4):

Using symbols like "n1" makes it complicated. I would rather use indexed symbols like "n[1]" or subscripted symbols.

```
Clear["Globals`*"]
num = 4;
as = Table[a[i, j], {i, num}, {j, num}]
ns = Table[n[i][t], {i, num}]
Do[n[i]'[t] = r[i] + n[i][t] (1 + as[[i]].ns), {i, num}]
```

This does define the derivatives:

```
n[2]'[t]

(* r[2] + n[2][t] (1 + a[2, 1] n[1][t] + a[2, 2] n[2][t] + a[2, 3] n[3][t] + a[2, 4] n[4][t]) *)
```

Using subscripted symbols this runs like:

```
Clear["Globals`*"]
num = 4;
as = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, num}, {j, num}]
ns = Table[Subscript[n, i][t], {i, num}]
Do[Subscript[n, i]'[t] = Subscript[r, i] + Subscript[n, i][t] (1 + as[[i]].ns), {i, num}]

Subscript[n, 2]'[t]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `Interactions` in my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo).  First, install the package (only needed first time):

```
PacletInstall["EcoEvo", "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master"]
```

Then load the package and define the model:

```
<< EcoEvo`
SetModel[{
  Guild[n] -> {
    Equation :> Subscript[r, \[FormalI]] Subscript[n, \[FormalI]] (1 + Sum[Subscript[a, \[FormalI], \[FormalJ]] Subscript[n, \[FormalJ]], {\[FormalJ], Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalN], n]}]),
    Traits -> {r}
  },
  Interaction[a] -> {Guilds -> {n, n}}
}];
```

All those special characters look better in Mathematica:

[image]

To generate your equations, use [`EcoEqns`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/EcoEqns.nb):

```
EcoEqns[{Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalN], n] -> 3}]
```

[image]

Of course you can do a lot more than generate the equations.  [`EcoSim`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/EcoSim.nb) will solve them:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
nsp = 20; (* number of species *)
tmax = 2000;
(* random interaction matrix *)
A = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 0.1/nsp}], {i, nsp}, {j, nsp}];
(* random growth rates *)
R = Table[RandomReal[], {nsp}];
sol = EcoSim[{a -> A, r -> R}, Table[Subscript[n, i] -> 0.1/nsp, {i, nsp}], tmax];

PlotDynamics[sol]
PlotGuild[sol, DataRange -> {All, {1, nsp}}]
```

[image]

[image]

The `Interactions` functionality isn't the best-developed yet, but see also [this example](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/tutorial/RandomLotka-Volterra.nb).